# Writing BMP data getting garbage

Tags: c++, graphics, bmp, fwrite

I'm working on understanding and drawing my own DLL for PDF417 (2d barcodes).  Anyhow, the actual drawing of the file is perfect, and in correct boundaries of 32 bits (as monochrome result).  At the time of writing the data, the following is a memory dump as copied from C++ Visual Studio memory dump of the pointer to the bmp buffer.  Each row is properly allocated to 36 wide before the next row.

Sorry about the wordwrap in the post, but my output was intended to be the same 36 bytes wide as the memory dump so you could better see the distortion.

The current drawing is 273 pixels wide by 12 pixels high, monochrome...

```
00 ab a8 61 d7 18 ed 18 f7 a3 89 1c dd 70 86 f5 f7 1a 20 91 3b c9 27 e7 67 12 1c 68 ae 3c b7 3e 02 eb 00 00
00 ab a8 61 d7 18 ed 18 f7 a3 89 1c dd 70 86 f5 f7 1a 20 91 3b c9 27 e7 67 12 1c 68 ae 3c b7 3e 02 eb 00 00
00 ab a8 61 d7 18 ed 18 f7 a3 89 1c dd 70 86 f5 f7 1a 20 91 3b c9 27 e7 67 12 1c 68 ae 3c b7 3e 02 eb 00 00
00 ab 81 4b ca 07 6b 9c 11 40 9a e6 0c 76 0a fc a3 33 70 bb 30 55 87 e9 c4 10 58 d9 ea 0d 48 3e 02 eb 00 00
00 ab 81 4b ca 07 6b 9c 11 40 9a e6 0c 76 0a fc a3 33 70 bb 30 55 87 e9 c4 10 58 d9 ea 0d 48 3e 02 eb 00 00
00 ab 81 4b ca 07 6b 9c 11 40 9a e6 0c 76 0a fc a3 33 70 bb 30 55 87 e9 c4 10 58 d9 ea 0d 48 3e 02 eb 00 00
00 ab 85 7e d0 29 e8 14 f4 0a 7a 05 3c 37 ba 86 87 04 db b6 09 dc a0 62 fc d1 31 79 bc 5c 0a 8e 02 eb 00 00
00 ab 85 7e d0 29 e8 14 f4 0a 7a 05 3c 37 ba 86 87 04 db b6 09 dc a0 62 fc d1 31 79 bc 5c 0a 8e 02 eb 00 00
00 ab 85 7e d0 29 e8 14 f4 0a 7a 05 3c 37 ba 86 87 04 db b6 09 dc a0 62 fc d1 31 79 bc 5c 0a 8e 02 eb 00 00
00 ab 85 43 c5 30 e2 26 70 4a 1a f3 e4 4d ce 2a 3f 79 cd bc e6 de 73 6f 39 b7 9c db ce 6d 5f be 02 eb 00 00
00 ab 85 43 c5 30 e2 26 70 4a 1a f3 e4 4d ce 2a 3f 79 cd bc e6 de 73 6f 39 b7 9c db ce 6d 5f be 02 eb 00 00
00 ab 85 43 c5 30 e2 26 70 4a 1a f3 e4 4d ce 2a 3f 79 cd bc e6 de 73 6f 39 b7 9c db ce 6d 5f be 02 eb 00 00
```

Here is the code to WRITE the file out -- verbatim immediately at the time of the memory dump from above

```
FILE *stream; 
if( fopen_s( &stream, cSaveToFile, "w+" ) == 0 ) 
{ 
   fwrite( &bmfh, 1, (UINT)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), stream ); 
   fwrite( &bmi, 1, (UINT)sizeof(BITMAPINFO), stream ); 
   fwrite( &RGBWhite, 1, (UINT)sizeof(RGBQUAD), stream );
   fwrite( ppvBits, 1, (UINT)bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, stream ); 
   fclose( stream ); 
}
```

Here's what ACTUALLY Gets written to the file.

```
00 ab a8 61 d7 18 ed 18 f7 a3 89 1c dd 70 86 f5 f7 1a 20 91 3b c9 27 e7 67 12 1c 68 ae 3c b7 3e 02 eb 00 00
00 ab a8 61 d7 18 ed 18 f7 a3 89 1c dd 70 86 f5 f7 1a 20 91 3b c9 27 e7 67 12 1c 68 ae 3c b7 3e 02 eb 00 00
00 ab a8 61 d7 18 ed 18 f7 a3 89 1c dd 70 86 f5 f7 1a 20 91 3b c9 27 e7 67 12 1c 68 ae 3c b7 3e 02 eb 00 00
00 ab 81 4b ca 07 6b 9c 11 40 9a e6 0c 76 0d 0a fc a3 33 70 bb 30 55 87 e9 c4 10 58 d9 ea 0d 48 3e 02 eb 00
00 00 ab 81 4b ca 07 6b 9c 11 40 9a e6 0c 76 0d 0a fc a3 33 70 bb 30 55 87 e9 c4 10 58 d9 ea 0d 48 3e 02 eb
00 00 00 ab 81 4b ca 07 6b 9c 11 40 9a e6 0c 76 0d 0a fc a3 33 70 bb 30 55 87 e9 c4 10 58 d9 ea 0d 48 3e 02
eb 00 00 00 ab 85 7e d0 29 e8 14 f4 0d 0a 7a 05 3c 37 ba 86 87 04 db b6 09 dc a0 62 fc d1 31 79 bc 5c 0d 0a
8e 02 eb 00 00 00 ab 85 7e d0 29 e8 14 f4 0d 0a 7a 05 3c 37 ba 86 87 04 db b6 09 dc a0 62 fc d1 31 79 bc 5c
0d 0a 8e 02 eb 00 00 00 ab 85 7e d0 29 e8 14 f4 0d 0a 7a 05 3c 37 ba 86 87 04 db b6 09 dc a0 62 fc d1 31 79
bc 5c 0d 0a 8e 02 eb 00 00 00 ab 85 43 c5 30 e2 26 70 4a 1a f3 e4 4d ce 2a 3f 79 cd bc e6 de 73 6f 39 b7 9c
db ce 6d 5f be 02 eb 00 00 00 ab 85 43 c5 30 e2 26 70 4a 1a f3 e4 4d ce 2a 3f 79 cd bc e6 de 73 6f 39 b7 9c
db ce 6d 5f be 02 eb 00 00 00 ab 85 43 c5 30 e2 26 70 4a 1a f3 e4 4d ce 2a 3f 79 cd bc e6 de 73 6f 39 b7 9c
db ce 6d 5f be 02 eb 00 00
```

Notice the start of the distortion with the "0d" in the result from reading the file back in the 4th line, about the 15th byte over...  Then, there are a few more staggered around which in total, skew the image off by 9 bytes worth...

Obviously, the drawing portion is working ok as everything remains properly aligned in memory for the 12 lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shouldn't you open the file in a compound mode i.e. writable & binary as in `wb+`?

> Notice the start of the distortion with the "0d"

That's ASCII code for Carriage Return (CR) -- added on some OSes with newline (where a newline is actually a sequence of CR/LF). This should go away once you start writing the output in binary mode.

Your code looks neat otherwise. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Your `0x0A` (`\n`) gets converted to DOS format `0x0D0A` (`\r\n`), becouse you're write the file in text mode. Switch to binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just did a similar thing in java (printing bmp data to a thermal receipt printer).  There are a couple of things i want to share with you:

1. bmp image data != an image format from microsoft.  the MS bitmap has about 54 bytes of header information before any image data.  (i spent a day or two working on this before I realized the difference)
2. bmp image data reads left to right, top to bottom, with the most significant bit on the left.
3. make sure the barcode image has a bitdepth of 1.  this means 1 bit = 1 pixel.  hexidecimal "ab" is 10101011 in binary, those 8 pixels will be filled in accordingly.
4. if you have a barcode 36 bytes wide, the barcode resolution is 288 x 12, not 273 x 12.  (36 * 8 = 288).
5. the image data should be 432 bytes in size (12 rows of 36 bytes).
6. i dont know what this means:

   > Anyhow, the actual drawing of the file is perfect, and in correct boundaries of 32 bits (as monochrome result).

monochrome means its either 1 color or another.  the pixel (think bit) is either filled in or it isnt.

Hope this helps